# Проблема с чтением файла

Tags: filestream, java

Суть проблемы. Есть файл, с занятной структурой: сначала общий заголовок, у указанием общей длины текста, затем идёт текст, разбитый на фреймы, в каждом фрейме так же есть заголовок с указанием идентификатора фрейма, длины текста в фрейме и байт отвечающий за кодировку текста. Вот так вот несколько фреймов, часть из которых нужно считать и распарсить. Проблема в том, чтобы подобрать нужную комбинацию потоков для чтения из файла. Первый заголовок считать и распарсить - без проблем, *RandomAccessFile* прекрасно с этим справляется, а вот дальше хуже, так как есть и просто байты с указанием длины или отвечающие за кодировку, и текст. Да и плюс нужно считать идентификатор(4 байта) чтобы понять нужно ли этот фрейм парсить или его можно пропустить. По-моему чистый *RandomAccessFile* с этим не очень хорошо справляется, либо я что-то неправильно делал(пытался читать байты четвёрками и сравнивать прочитанное с нужными мне идентификаторами фреймов). Есть мысль, что можно объединить *RandomAccessFile* с буферизированным потоком для облегчения задачи, хотя, я могу ошибаться, опыта немного.
Подскажите, как лучше решить подобную задачку?
Заранее спасибо за помошь

Comment: читайте его побайтно и складывайте нужные данные в массив

Comment: Хм... То есть, RandomAccessFile'ом читать побайтно, парсить заголовки, те что не нужны пропускать, благо длина фрейма есть. А как быть с текстом? Там может быть текст в трех кодировках(3 вида UTF и одна ISO). Получится ли перевести байтовые последовательности в символы без лишних хлопот? Или лучше на текст в зависимости от байта кодировки применять свои методы чтения - для одной побайтно, для другой - как символы UTF?

Comment: Зачем сложно? Считайте последовательность байт, скормите её [CharsetDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html)'у. Или [сконструируйте](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

Comment: Спасибо большое за наводку на сей класс. Параллельно нашел способ перекодирования через Charset с прямым заданием кодировки, попробую оба

Answer (score 1):

Структура файла напрямую говорит о том, что файл предназначен для потокового чтения. Такая структура была типична в свое время для чтения ленточных данных (в эру когда еще были живы носители на лентах).

Поэтому читать как random access не очень логично. Надо читать его потоком, вопрос только в том бинарный это файл или текстовый. Если текстовый то чтение типа:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
// blah-blah
}
```

должно нормально справиться с задачей, ну возможно еще с заданием кодовой страницы через `FileInputStream`

Если файл бинарный, то надо применить уже нечто вроде `DataInputStream` (если знаете какие примитивы надо читать), а если нет, то ничего не остается как брать шашку в руки типа `ByteArrayInputStream`

Comment: Шутка юмора в том, что содержимое смешанное - часть просто как байты, часть как текст. ReadAccessFile несколько удобнее за счет возможности пропустить ненужные фреймы, но я могу и ошибаться. Попробую и Ваш метод, спасибо большое.